# How do I remove repeated WebElement from ArrayList Selenium WebDriver JAVA?

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I have an `ArrayList` of `WebElement`, and I want to remove repeated strings from it. How can I do this? Kindly advise. Thank you.

HTML:

```
<li data-id="20151105031XJ500wh0001" data-istrace="0" class="evenTr first">
   <span class="wd1">2015-11-05 16:10:58</span>
   <span class="wd5">3D福彩</span>
   <span title="一码不定胆">一码不定胆</span>
   <span class="wd2">2015302</span>
   <span class="wd3">元</span>
   <span class="grid-toggle" alt="号码详情：">
    <div class="wrapbox">
      <em alt="2">2</em>
      </div>
      </span>
   <span class="wd4">1</span>
   <span>¥2</span>
   <span>¥0</span>
   <span class="wd4">未开奖</span>
   <span alt="开奖号码："></span>
   <span class="wd3">否</span>
</li>
```

Here's my code:

```
List<String> spanText = new ArrayList<String>();
List<WebElement> we = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li/span[@alt='号码详情：']"));
Set<WebElement> hs = new LinkedHashSet<WebElement>();

hs.addAll(we);
System.out.print("Value of addall" + hs + "----");
we.clear();
we.addAll(hs);
System.out.print("Value of we" + we + "----");

for (WebElement w : we)
{
    spanText.add(w.getText());
    System.out.print("Value of" + spanText + "done - ");
}
```

The result I am getting was duplicate and I need the value only:

```
Value of[2, 047, 查看全部, 28, 18, 18, 18, 28, 28, 28]
```

Image of the dialog Element:

[Image WebElement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8r9ZI.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to loop through the `List` of `WebElement`s and see if the `.getText()` is already contained in your `Set`. If it isn't then add it.

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li/span[@alt='号码详情：']"));
Set<String> hs = new LinkedHashSet<>();
for (WebElement element : elements)
{
    if (!hs.contains(element.getText()))
    {
        hs.add(element.getText());
    }
}
```